# Which SFF work first showed "Luck" superpower?

Tags: history-of

I have encountered Luck superpower several times. Some examples which are in my mind:

- In *Deadpool 2* (2018) movie, there was a mutant girl in X-Force team who had this superpower.
- In *Harry Potter* series, *Felix Felicis* potion temporarily grants people this superpower (this potion was introduced in 2005).
- In a 90s cartoon, Galactus picked a girl from Earth because she had a special gene which granted her Luck. He made her his herald (her herald look was girl on fire).

Which SFF work first showed this "Luck" superpower?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/discussion.php?id=xmiec05inlabzcct9v18z5xc&trope=DiscardedYKTTW

Comment: @Valorum This looks superset of what I am asking.

Comment: Teela Brown in Niven's 1970 [*Ringworld*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld)?

Comment: https://doomsdayer.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/bester-alfred-oddy-and-id-1950/ - 1951

Comment: The Weapon Shops of Isher - 1951

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_on_the_Barnhouse_Effect - 1950

Comment: @Valorum Wikipedia plot summary of Weapon Shops of Isher doesn't have luck word. The Barnhouse one only features Psychokinesis superpower.

Comment: @Valorum Forgot about Bester's "Oddy and Id". Good one. Published in the August 1950 *Astounding*.

Comment: What about Lester del Rey's ["The Luck of Ignatz"](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_British_Ed._v01n01_1939-08) (1938)? Does the Venusian *zloaht*'s luck qualify as a superpower?

Comment: Red Dwarf, Quarantine (1992) "Things look pretty bad, but by using the luck virus taken from the Viral Research Department, Lister is able to guess the door code to get them out of quarantine. Now on the run from Rimmer, Kryten has a plan to purge the holo-virus from his system. Thanks to the luck virus, all the equipment that's needed just happens to be lying at their feet. Just in the nick of time, Kryten activates the purge and Rimmer is cured. After being informed that Rimmer will be fine, Lister takes it as a sign the luck virus has worn off."

Comment: @jim `Luck Virus`. Wow! Creativity on overdrive.. :)

Comment: @user14111 Niven's 1967 "[Safe at Any Speed]( http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45172)" has this same Known Space premise and predates _Ringworld_. But as you know,  better answers have appeared.

Comment: @Spencer Really? It's been a long time since I read "Safe at Any Speed" but I seem to recall that the guy survives because of engineering, not luck.

Comment: @user14111 IIRC Niven's commentary on this (final)  story in the _Known Space_ anthology says that he stopped writing KS stories because the "fundamental change in human nature" made it impossible to develop believable characters. Perhaps I was adding 2+2 and getting 22.

Comment: I thought of Gladstone Gander (first appeared in1948). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladstone_Gander

Comment: Another example of luck as a superpower is Marve's Longshot, who was introduced in Longshot #1 in 1985. Certainly not the first, though.

Comment: Not the first but one of the quirkiest: *Strange Luck*, an early nineties TV show about a guy with **lots** of luck, both good and bad.

Comment: The oldest luck story that I know of is "Code Duello" by Mack Reynolds, from 1968. In this story, an interstellar government agency assembles a group of agents with various special talents, one of which is luck.