# What is the significance of the Red Lotus?

Tags: history-of, inspiration, fantasy-genre

The theme of a Red Lotus seems to show up in various fantasy works. For instance:

- In *Ice Fantasy*, where the Red Lotus seems to a magical flower of great power.
- In *The Legend of Korra*, where it is an organization.
- In DC, where it denotes a mutant character.

And elsewhere. Notably, all these examples seem to have an East Asian influence, probably specifically from China.

What's the inspiration for this? Is there some mythological or other antecedent?

Comment: From the little knowledge I have, "Red" is oftenly linked to good fortune, whilst the lotus has a lot of possible meaning.

Comment: This seems excessively broad. Each of these are different properties written and designed by different people. What inspired one ("*my mother used to grow red lotuses*") might be completely dissimilar to another ("*It was the name of my favourite chinese takeaway"*)

Comment: @Valorum The symbolic meaning of the lotus in East Asian thought is well-established: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padma_(attribute) ...which has nothing to do Chinese restaurants. It's rather presumptuous to dismiss it as more likely to be a random personal connection than, for instance, a symbol found everywhere that there are Buddhists.

Comment: @recognizer - Sure, and while those [restaurants](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRzLXF6irF9207RSSarPi6oR90NKwdIcpcOaNPkhpV-uIvhWtlMyg) may themselves be inspired by eastern mythology and culture, who's to say that that's what has inspired the use of this symbology in a *range* of differing properties?

Comment: The White Lotus was a religious and political movement in Chinese history, or several different ones with the same name, a hybrid of Buddhism and Manichaeism.  It inspired the White Lotus Rebellion in the 1330s, The Red Turban Rebellion that founded the Ming Dynasty, and the White Lotus Rebellion of 1796-1804.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Lotus_Rebellion  Another example of the importance of the Lotus symbol, and also combined with a color.

Comment: @Valorum - The *point* is that it's a common theme. I could add another half-dozen examples if you want.

Comment: @Adamant - Adding additional examples makes the question worse, not better. Unless you have some reason to think that every single writer who's every mention a red lotus has had precisely the same inspiration.

Comment: @Valorum - Ummmm, it's apparently a trope in Chinese fantasy. You can ignore that if you want...but I'd like to know where it comes from.

Comment: @Adamant - And while that may well be true, the fact that its a trope doesn't mean that the writers of Ice Fantasy and Legend of Korra had exactly the same inspiration to use it. One might be referencing its use in Buddhist mythology, another might be referencing the Chinese usage. My point is that asking about one is fine, asking about more than one is too broad.

Comment: I assure you that if it has a significance in Buddhism and in Chinese thought, the two are probably historically connected. If I wanted to know why so many evil people were associated with 108 in Asian fantasy, would you say it was just the address of the author's favorite restaurant?

Comment: We have *plenty* of questions about the origins of tropes that could well, on occasion, have more than one source. Do all [luck superpowers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188885/51379) have the same inspiration, for instance? While it would be nice if I could show you a TV Tropes page, I'd already have the answer if I could do that.

Comment: That question asks about the *first mention of the luck superpower*. If it asked about whether all mentions of the luck superpower were inspired by the same source, I'd vote to close it.

Comment: "The point is that it's a common theme. I could add another half-dozen examples if you want. " - by that standard here are some other common themes "mountains", "lakes", "trees", "doors", etc...objects appearing in things does not a theme make, unless the makers intend it to be so. Thus, the question is too broad unless every maker ever agrees that such a thing means such a thing. Narrow it down or its too broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Black Lotus of Stygia originates in the writings of Robert E. Howard specifically in Red Nails serialised in Weird Tales July - October 1936. In mythology the red lotus is associated with the Buddha, but Howard using the black lotus as a sorcerous source of drugged sleep probably has in mind the story of the lotus-eaters. These drugged 'lotophagi' were encountered by Odysseus in Homer's Odyssey: https://www.britannica.com/topic/Lotus-Eater.

From Howard, lotuses of various colours (grey, emerald etc) made their way into sword and sorcery, and hence fantasy fiction.

This route leads the Ice Fantasy flower. Meanwhile the general association of the lotus blossom with China and the east gives the usage for organisations and or asiatic superheroes.

In re: buddhism see here: https://lotusmeaning.com/red-lotus-flower-meaning/#tab-con-1 . Also worth noting the famous Buddhist mantra Om-Mani-Padmi-Hum, is "the jewel of the lotus chant".

Comment: That line about the Red Lotus being associated with Buddha is the most relevant, if true. Could you cite it?